# How can the CustomerRef field from SalesTable be added to the CustAccountStatementExt report?

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

In Microsoft Dynamics Ax2012 R2 I want a customization for report `CustAccountStatementExt` by adding the field `CustomerRef` from `SalesTable`

Location of report in the AOT :

```
SSRS Reports\Reports\CustAccountStatementExt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, I have no idea whatsoever what you are asking. It may be worth taking a step back and looking at a couple of upvoted questions for guidance how to ask.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We'd like to do the same thing and obviously need to work out how to get from CustTrans to SalesTable; is you've already got this, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open Visual studio 2010 (only supported version for AX 2012 R2) and open this repot from *Application Explorer* (View -> Application Explorer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

MSDN:

- [Walkthrough: Customizing Existing Microsoft Dynamics AX Reports](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc567629.aspx)
- [How to: Customize a Report](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc569485.aspx)

[image: Edit SSRS Report]

Visual Studio Tools for AX must be installed from the AX Setup.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Matej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28931892/2720554) (which only covers the customization of the report layout) you also have to make the field available in the report data source. To do that you have to add a new field to table `CustAccountStatementExtTmp` that will hold the value of the `CustomerRef` field from table `SalesTable`.

You will also have to customize the creation of the `CustAccountStatementExtTmp` records which in this case is surprisingly done in the report controller class `CustAccountStatementExtController` (usually the report tables are filled in the data provider class). This will require some work, because you have no direct way to access the `SalesTable` record there. Basically you have to figure out how to determine the sales order from the `CustTrans` record that is available there.

After that, you still have to customize `CustAccountStatementExtDP.insertNewRecords` method because for some reason the records are copied from one instance of the (temporary) table `CustAccountStatementExtTmp` to another.

After that the new field should show up in the data set of the report in Visual Studio and you can then include it in the report layout (see [Matej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28931892/2720554) on how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed to accomplish this:

1. Add field to the CustAccountStatementExtTmp table
2. Add code to CustAccountStatementExtController.insertCustAccountStatementExtTmp method to populate the new field.
3. Refresh the data source in the SSRS report, and in the report design (and then re-open the design).
4. Add the field to the report
5. At this point I also had to restart the AOS before the data would appear on the report.  Apparently there was something cached in memory that prevented it from working.